# How find two principal components with PCA

Tags: python, math, pca

I have two arrays. It looks like:

```
       GarageMudroomLights [kW]  DiningRoomOutlets [kW]
0                      0.001159                0.000000
1                      0.001223                0.000000
2                      0.001281                0.000000
3                      0.001525                0.000000
4                      0.001549                0.000000
5                      0.001490                0.000000
...                         ...                     ...
39796                  0.003750                0.001783
39797                  0.003717                0.001850
39798                  0.003617                0.001867
```

I need to find principal components like two orthogonal vectors.
I've tried to get it with [PCA in python](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/principal-component-analysis/), but I can't understand where is components there, where is the rotation angle between vectors ([necessary vectors and angle (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAUsI.png)) and how it works only with two arrays.

Now I'm standardized arrays and don't understand what's next.

```
import pandas
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

s_i_t = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',')
s_i_t_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(s_i_t)
```

Comment: This is not really a programming question - or is it? Seems you got math's problems and how to apply PCA to your data ... which would make it a quite broad topic.

Comment: The components would be the two eigenvectors. The eigenvector with the larger eigenvalue will be the component with the 'most' information. The real point of PCA is reduction of correlated data. Is there really a point with just 2 arrays unless you are just trying to find out if the second array is correlated to the first in which case your second eigenvalue will be very small?